# Babel failing to compile es6 angular factory

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

I'm pretty new at es6, but I've been doing angular for a while now.

I do not understand why the below code doesn't transpile by Babel.  Test it yourself by pasting into https://babeljs.io/.

The error is that it expects a `(` at the start of the `const singleDocumentSample` which seems to be an incorrectly reported error.  I tried variations of

`const xx;
   xx = {};`
just in case it was initialization-related.  I tried changing to `let` and even `var`.  What is going on?

Whole code file below:

```js
class FakeData {
    constructor($httpBackend) {
        'ngInject';
        this.$httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    }

    initialize() {
        this.$httpBackend.whenGET('/v1/api/documents').respond(function () {
            return [200, getAllDocuments()];
        });

        this.$httpBackend.whenGET(/\/v1\/api\/documents\/[1-9][0-9]*/).respond(function () {
            return [200, getDocumentById()];
        });
    }

    getAllDocuments() {
        return allDocumentsSample;
    }

    getDocumentById() {
        return singleDocumentSample;
    }

    const singleDocumentSample = {
        "id": "5728fdb8e4b04adb356afb87",
        "fileName": "6454841.xlsx",
        "contentType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        "fileExtension": "xlsx",
        "uploadDate": "2016-05-03T19:36:24Z",
        "thumbnails": [

        ],
        "thumbnailsDetailed": null,
        "fileSize": 11467,
        "description": "",
        "position": null,
        "confidential": null,
        "customMetadata": null,
        "who": {
            "creationDate": "2016-05-03T19:36:24Z",
            "lastUpdateDate": "2016-05-03T19:36:24Z",
            "createdBy": {
                "userName": "hawkslee",
                "fullName": "Hawksley, Emma",
                "userId": 49952
            },
            "lastUpdatedBy": {
                "userName": "hawkslee",
                "fullName": "Hawksley, Emma",
                "userId": 49952
            }
        },
        "url": "http://attachments-api.apps.wwt.com/api/attachments/5728fdb8e4b04adb356afb87/file"
    };

    const allDocumentsSample = {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "5728fdb8e4b04adb356afb87",
                "fileName": "6454841.xlsx",
                "contentType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                "fileExtension": "xlsx",
                "uploadDate": "2016-05-03T19:36:24Z",
                "thumbnails": [

                ],
                "thumbnailsDetailed": null,
                "fileSize": 11467,
                "description": "",
                "position": null,
                "confidential": null,
                "customMetadata": null,
                "who": {
                    "creationDate": "2016-05-03T19:36:24Z",
                    "lastUpdateDate": "2016-05-03T19:36:24Z",
                    "createdBy": {
                        "userName": "hawkslee",
                        "fullName": "Hawksley, Emma",
                        "userId": 49952
                    },
                    "lastUpdatedBy": {
                        "userName": "hawkslee",
                        "fullName": "Hawksley, Emma",
                        "userId": 49952
                    }
                },
                "url": "http://attachments-api.apps.wwt.com/api/attachments/5728fdb8e4b04adb356afb87/file"
            }
        ],
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 50,
            "pageCount": 456,
            "sort": "id",
            "order": "asc",
            "itemCount": 22799,
            "nextPageUrl": null,
            "previousPageUrl": null
        }
    };
}

appModule.factory('fakeData', $httpBackend => new FakeData($httpBackend));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error in your code… - it is not allowed to have const declaration in class body(in current syntax you can define only methods there).

Instead, you need to declare this const's as object properties, or move it out from class declaration.